# ssl passenger nginx rails 4 routing combine wrong port with https

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, nginx, passenger

I folowed the rails tutorial org tuto and made a web site
Installed passenger, nginx.
 Works perfectly on prod env on heroku=>
http://klat.herokuapp.com/  (app not finished but still better than nothing)

Here i use the =>

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

(only for heroku)

my routes from routes.rb =>

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'users/new'
    root                        'static_pages#home'
    get 'help'      =>          'static_pages#help'
    get 'about'     =>          'static_pages#about'
    get 'contact'   =>          'static_pages#contact'
    get 'login'     =>          'static_pages#login'
    get 'signup'    =>          'users#new'
    resources :users
end
```

~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc got

```
#a generated key
export SECRET_KEY_BASE="my_very_big_generated_key"
export SECRET_TOKEN="my_very_big_generated_key"
```

I generated with openssl my own certificates

```
ls ../cert/
server.crt  server.csr  server.key  server.key.org  server.pem
```

And I launch my server with this command in local

```
passenger start -p 2000 --ssl-certificate ../cert/server.csr  --ssl-port 20001  -e production
```

I passed two days to get to this point but i can't find out why my server starts at

```
http ://0.0.0.0:2000/
```

and redirects at

```
https ://0.0.0.0:2000
```

and no one page is accessible: error

```
An error occurred during a connection to 0.0.0.0:2000. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

But in logs we clearly see

```
App 12832 stdout: 
App 12854 stdout: 
App 12854 stdout: Started HEAD "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-24 18:09:30 +0200
App 12854 stdout: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
{... rendering homepage wiht _header.erb _footer.erb etc ...}
```

So i can visit my website non rendered with css at address:

```
http: //127.0.0.1:2000/
```

and i still getting those messages from my nginx server

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/rails.png"):

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css"):

{...and more ...}
```

I commented in every file in my ruby on rails app all ssl_force
when i uncomment in config/production.rb

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

for local use, i get
on

```
http ://127.0.0.1:2000/ => redirect to https ://127.0.0.1:2000/ and get => (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
http ://127.0.0.1 => unable to locate
https ://127.0.0.1 => unable to locate
http ://127.0.0.1:2000 => unable to locate
http ://127.0.0.1:2001 => unable to locate
https ://127.0.0.1:2000 => unable to locate
https ://127.0.0.1:2001 => unable to locate
```

Just can't find out why my openssl generated keys don't work, the pages are not rendered with css and other ressources, it's maybe a routing problem...

A little help is much appreciated!

PS: (But please no help such as "use Thin or Puma or another server, i have a constraint to use at choice nginx, lighthttpd or Apache (the obvious answer is nginx for me)")
And to set up my own ssl certification in my own server is a constraint too in my studies

Comment: first of all i deactivated force ssl in all files i found in my app; so i dont get wrong routes with wrong ports     several commands helped me  to install all bundles in production mode : bundle --deployment ; rake assets:precompile ; echo "export RAILS_ENV=production" >> ~/.bash_profile ; rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production" after all that, i got bach my css and database correct on prod on localhost; keep trying to make ssl work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally

the command i did to start my server without errors is

```
passenger start --ssl-certificate ../cert/server.crt  --ssl-certificate-key ../cert/server.key  -e production --ssl
```

without specifying the ssl port and standart port

i added

```
    gem 'rack-ssl', :require => 'rack/ssl'
```

to my gem file
and did several bundle install/--deployment etc...

set up in production.rb

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

and in application_controller.rb

```
force_ssl
```

so my connection is encrypted now as i connect to

https://0.0.0.0:3000/

BUT...
I'm still unhappy with all those configurations because of the presence of the port number in the url

Anyway, it will do for now...